# error in running command using subprocess.run()

Tags: python, bash, scripting, subprocess

I am going nuts.

This command, when run inside a WSL1 Ubuntu 20.04 terminal inside Windows10, works well and produces a bunch of files inside the current directory, when having the executable `smilei` one folder above and the .py inside the current folder.

`mpirun -n 1 ../smilei namelist_Xe_GPtrial_noOAM_a0included.py`

I now want it to run the exact same command using Python's `subprocess`.

What am I doing wrong:

```
particular_namelist_name = "namelist_Xe_GPtrial_noOAM_a0included.py"
cp = subprocess.run(["mpirun", "-n", "1", "../smilei", particular_namelist_name], check=True, text=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

This results in the error:

```
CalledProcessError: Command '['mpirun', '-n', '1', '../smilei', 'namelist_Xe_GPtrial_noOAM_a0included.py']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

I tried to debug it, however inside that folder there is nothing, apart from the .py.

I tried to use (for the above command, but without the check=True keyword value):

```
print(cp.stdout) # prints an empty line
print(cp.stderr) # prints an empty line
print(cp.returncode) # prints 1
```

How can I debug this? What I am doing wrong?
The same thing happens with `subprocess.Popen(...)`.

I don't want to use `shell=True`.

Thank you!

Comment: How do you run your script? Do you use Python installed inside your Ubuntu in WSL or Python installed on the main Windows system?

Comment: Can you check the returncode on the platform where you run it normally?

Comment: @DmitriOvodok  , I run the jupyter notebook inside a Visual Studio Code summoned via $ code . written inside a WSL1 terminal installed on Windows10 laptop. Then I press the run all command from the notebook (in VSC). It says the interpreter is located at ``/bin/python3``. I can chose between this and another interpreter located at ``/usr/bin/python3``.

Comment: @DmitriOvodok, when I run a simple .py inside the WSL1 terminal, I write ``python3 script.py``. Doing ``which python3`` inside the WSL1 terminal, I get as output: ``/usr/bin/python3``. So I assume I need to select this interpreter path inside the VSCode?

Comment: @velenos14 The error may just be due to the relative path. You can use the `os.path.abspath` to get the full paths for the python file and the `smilei` file. It would remove the chances of error due to incorrect paths.

Comment: @Ron, I have tried what you say: ``cp = subprocess.run(["mpirun", "-n", "1", str(os.path.abspath("../smilei")), str(os.path.abspath(particular_namelist_name))],  text=True)``, but this fails as well, similarly if I remove the str preceeding the os.path.abspath calls

Comment: @velenos14 Can you print out these paths and make sure that they are correct?

Comment: Can you run the script and then run `echo $?` to check the return code in Bash?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238689/discussion-between-ron-and-velenos14).